# Task as Return type and without return type in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand some concept regarding the Task but getting some issues as the following function.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        { 
            int d =newcall();
            Console.WriteLine("This is the result after function call");
            Console.WriteLine(d);
       }

 public  static int newcall()
        {
            Task<int> n = new Task<int>(()=> {

                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Console.WriteLine("Hello This is the inside the task");
                return 3;
            
            
            });
          
            n.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("This is the after task call");
           
            return n.Result;
        }
```

`In this case i get the result as:`
`This is the after task call`
`Hello This is the inside the task`
`Hello This is after the result call`
`3`

Now the second case is when return the task as the return type without async(I understand the async return type I am trying to understand the task as the return type without that)

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { Task<int> d =newcall();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello This is after the result call");
            Console.WriteLine(d.Result);
}
 public  static Task<int> newcall()
        {
            Task<int> n = new Task<int>(()=> {

                Thread.Sleep(10000);
                Console.WriteLine("Hello This is the inside the task");
                return 3;         
            });
          
            n.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("This is the after task call");  
            return n;
        }
```

`In this case result is :`
`This is the after task call`
`Hello This is after the result call`
`Hello This is the inside the task`
`3`

Now in the first case it looks like it is blocking the main thread.  but in the sencond case it does not happen. the only difference between the two is the in the second case we have a return type as a Task and in the first case it is int.

So why it gives the response like this. what is the meaning of the return type as a task without async method. (I am creating the new task inside the function in both the case.so as per my understanding it both should give the same response).

can any one help in understanding this. I have checked the stackoverflow but find the soltion with respect to async.

Thanks

Comment: Second case does block the main thread. d.Result blocks main thread until task is completed.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.Result`, you'll block your current thread if the `Task` is not yet completed. Observe where your two calls to `.Result` are and the output results aren't a mystery, hopefully.

Note that there's nothing special about "returning a `Task` without `async`" - `async` is consumed at compile time, and what you end up with is *a plain old method that returns a `Task`*.

Comment: Thanks,  I have one doubt is there any benefit of calling return type as Task without an async modifier.   what happen when we give the Task<T> as a return type in case of non-async method. Why and when we should it.

Comment: @user9582192 `async`/`await` are only used at development time. When you compile your code, they are replaced. Something like this: `public async Task DoFoo() { await DoBar(); DoSyncStuff(); }` will be "translated" to something like this: `public Task DoFoo() { return DoBar().ContinueWith(t => DoSyncStuff()); }`